# view based iphone development question

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I am trying to develop and app that will display a number or text and the user will physically speek the said number or text then touch the number or text and a new window will show another number or text

and this will continue many times

how should i go about developing this?

Comment: Bear in mind that the apps that recognize voice audio, they all ship the audio data off to a server running sophisticated and expensive software.  You're not going to pull that off locally.

Answer (score 0):

Brian, first of all you should take a look at UIViewController Class Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

This file will help you a lot, you'll know how to manage different view controllers, and it's basically what you need.

Second thing is: to touch the number or text it's OK, but to speak and your app recognize it, it's a little bit harder. I would suggest you to develop the touch control and after you finish with this, maybe you can start to study a way to develop the speakable control.

Third, as a basic model, you should think in instantiate an NSArray with the "right" content, I mean, the content that should be touched to go to next "step".
Create a button with this "right content" and for every touch in the screen you call a method to check if the touch was inside the right button or not.

You can use one UIViewController for each index of this array, or you can use always the same UIViewController and just change the words or numbers on the screen with some custom method.

Hope it helps.